# Passing arguments to views in Django from constrained choices

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am looking for the best way to pass either of two arguments to the views from the URL, without allowing any additional arguments.

For example, with the following URLs:

```
(r'^friends/requests', 'app.views.pendingFriends'),

(r'^friends/offers', 'app.views.pendingFriends'),
```

If it's possible to pass the URL to the views, so that `pendingFriends` knows which URL it was called from, that would work. However, I can't see a way to do this.

Instead, I could supply the arguments (`requests` or `offers`) in the URL, to a single Django view,

```
(r'^friends/(?P<type>\w+', 'app.views.pendingFriends'),
```

The argument will tell `pendingFriends` what to do. However, this leaves open the possibility of other arguments being passed to the URL (besides `requests` and `offers`.)

Ideally I'd like the URL dispatcher to stop this happening (via a 404) before the invalid arguments get passed to the views. So my questions are (a) is this the best approach, (b) is there a way to constrain the arguments which are passed to the views in the URL to `requests` or `offers`?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that you have the full power of regexes to match URLs.  You simply need to write a regex that accepts only what you want:

```
(r'^friends/(?P<type>requests|offers)', 'app.views.pendingFriends'),
```

If you want to list it twice, do it like this:

```
(r'^friends/(?P<type>requests)', 'app.views.pendingFriends'),
(r'^friends/(?P<type>offers)', 'app.views.pendingFriends'),
```